# How to change url in user browser without client redirect in servlet

Tags: java, url, servlets, redirect, forward

I want to forward from one page to another but with the same I want url to be changed. Suppose user is here http://mywebsite/register and when he completes his registration process then I want this in his address bar http://mywebsite/home

Is it possible without using sendRedirect , I mean by the way server side forwarding only? or any other way around to this problem?

Comment: I would do a redirect (client-side), so if the user refreshes the page, it doesn't go through the registration process again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just let the HTML form submit to that URL directly.

```html
<form action="http://mywebsite/home">
```

But this makes no sense. You'll also run into problems when redisplaying the same form with validation messages in case of validation failure. You'd need to redirect back to the original page if you intend to keep the original URL and you'd need to fiddle with storing messages in the session scope instead of the request scope because a redirect basically creates a brand new request. You'll without a redirect also run in "double submit" problem whenever the enduser presses F5 after submitting the form.

Just let the servlet redirect the successful POST request to the desired URL. That's the canonical approach. Even more, this is a recommend "design pattern": the [POST-Redirect-GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: thanks a lot, you cleared my several doubts in just one post. I was just wondering whether it is possible from server side or not and if not then why.

Comment: The `response.sendRedirect(url)` **is** the server-side way to send a redirect. The client-side way would be `window.location = url;` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no way around a redirect since the browser has to update the url at some point. And if you'd update the url after the forwarded to page has been loaded it would issue a refresh and the page would be loaded again (which might result in an endless loop).

Why don't you want to use a redirect in that case?

Comment: got it. I was just curious to know,can we do this from server itself without sending a redirect